# Laravel 5.2 subdomain with different sessions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel. I have created a domain and subdomain with a specific domain group.

*domain.com*

*admin.domain.com*

On my domain.com a user can login. And in the subdomain admin.domain.com an admin can login. The problem Im having is when a user is logged in the root domain the admin subdomain is also logged in. I want the root domain and subdomain to be of different sessions. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not on framework, I got this problem when I worked with `Yii 2.0` too, the issue because sessions general from application key, the solution is **make key different between root and subdomain**.

The solution here is you have to general another `Laravel Application key` on your subdomain follow [the document](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3):

```
php artisan key:generate
```

> Application key [Idgz1PE3zO9iNc0E3oeH3CHDPX9MzZe3] set successfully.

2 keys in root and subdomain have to different.

Hope this help.

Comment: How do I assign different keys when the root domain and subdomain are using the same .env file?

Comment: Hmm, I think you should create a new one or declare another key variable  for subdomain.

Comment: That means a separate Laravel project folder for the admin subdomain? hmm

Comment: I think so, let try another solution for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel by default uses a single cookie to keep session data and manage its authentication system, thats why your user keeps logged across your subdomains, because your cookie is still there.

In this case I think you have 2 options:

1st: Create a different auth system using middlewares for each subdomain group to manage sessions (lets say you create/read a different cookie for each subdomain, but this could be a little bit tricky if the same user want to use the app across different subdomains at the "same time").

2nd: Use a different session driver (lets say database e.g.)